# phpbb wrong post order

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I have this problem on my phpbb board that sometimes when two users post in the same minute their posts are displayed in the wrong order. It even happens that the first post is already visible before the other user decides to reply, then when the user has posted, the post is displayed before the previous post.

Some users also report the forum 'clock' to be two minutes behind the real time.

I can't find a similar problem anywhere on the web. Does anyone have a clue what might have caused this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: The forum 'clock' is based off of your server time.  When you look at the time on the posts, do they match up with the user's claim that earlier response is still coming first?

Comment: The time on the posts don't match up with the user's claims. It shows like the newer post was actually posted before the older post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took this up to the host, although they denied it was a server time problem, it was fixed after I reported it.
My guess is that the problem was caused by a synchronisation issue in the server-cluster (and that the host didn't want to admit it). The problem first occurred shortly after a (problematic) server update.